# What does the following Python code do? It's like a list comprehension with parentheses.

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm researching web crawlers made in Python, and I've stumbled across a pretty simple one. But, I don't understand the last few lines, highlighted in the following code:

```
import sys
import re
import urllib2
import urlparse

tocrawl = [sys.argv[1]]
crawled = []

keywordregex = re.compile('<meta\sname=["\']keywords["\']\scontent=["\'](.*?)["\']\s/>')
linkregex = re.compile('<a\s(?:.*?\s)*?href=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>')

while 1:
    crawling = tocrawl.pop(0)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(crawling)
    msg = response.read()
    keywordlist = keywordregex.findall(msg)
    crawled.append(crawling)
    links = linkregex.findall(msg)
    url = urlparse.urlparse(crawling)

    a = (links.pop(0) for _ in range(len(links))) //What does this do?

    for link in a:
        if link.startswith('/'):
            link = 'http://' + url[1] + link
        elif link.startswith('#'):
            link = 'http://' + url[1] + url[2] + link
        elif not link.startswith('http'):
            link = 'http://' + url[1] + '/' + link

        if link not in crawled:
            tocrawl.append(link)
```

That line looks like some kind of a list comprehension to me, but I'm not sure and I need an explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and it simply empties the list `links` as you iterate over it.

They could have replaced this part

```
a = (links.pop(0) for _ in range(len(links))) //What does this do?

for link in a:
```

With this:

```
while links:
    link = links.pop(0)
```

And it would work the same. But since popping from the end of a list is more efficient, this would be better than either:

```
links.reverse()
while links:
    link = links.pop()
```

Of course, if you're fine with following the links in reverse order (I don't see why they need to be processed in order), it would be even more efficient to not reverse the `links` list and just pop off the end.

Comment: i dont see how reversing the list, and then popping from the list will be more efficient, you are still popping from the start, just now the list is reversed... shouldn't you `pop(-1)` or something ? (if that is possible)

Comment: `pop()` (i.e. with no parameter) pops from the end of a list.

Comment: @Inbar The `-1` is implicit when called with no arguments. Popping off the middle of a list is less efficient because python has to move all the following items one space to the left in memory.

Comment: @lazyr yes im aware of this, i didnt know the -1 was implicit. now it makes sense. thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: @lazyr -- nice answer. You not only answered the question, you made the code more efficient *and* readable.

Answer (score 2):

It creates a generator which will take objects off the links list.

To explain:

`range(len(links))` returns a list of numbers from 0 up to, but not including, the length of the links list.  So if links contains `[ "www.yahoo.com", "www.google.com", "www.python.org" ]`, then it will generate a list [ 0, 1, 2 ].

`for _ in blah`, just loops over the list, throwing away the result.

`links.pop(0)` removes the first item from links.

The entire expression returns a generator which pops items from the head of the links list.

And lastly, a demonstration in a python console:

```
>>> links = [ "www.yahoo.com", "www.google.com", "www.python.org "]
>>> a = (links.pop(0) for _ in range(len(links)))
>>> a.next()
'www.yahoo.com'
>>> links
['www.google.com', 'www.python.org ']
>>> a.next()
'www.google.com'
>>> links
['www.python.org ']
>>> a.next()
'www.python.org '
>>> links
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = (links.pop(0) for _ in range(len(links)))
```

can also be written as:

```
a = []
for _ in range(len(links)):
    a.append(links.pop(0))
```

**EDIT:**

only the only difference is when using the generator it is done lazily, so items are only popped from links as they are requested through a. and not all at once, when dealing with lots of data then it is much more efficient, and there is no way to do this without using advanced pythonic functions.

Comment: I don't get in which regard `a` differs from `links`?

Comment: `links` cannot be iterated over i suppose. and so the code is simply migrating all the data in `links` to `a`

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but: Couldn't I simply write `for link in links`? I will probably have to read about generator expressions, but so far for this particular case I don't see the need to do this conversion.

Comment: @JakobS. no, you could not just write `for link in links` because `links` is not a normal list, its a regex object.

Comment: No, you couldn't do that, @JakobS. `links`, apparently, isn't iterable, I tried.

Comment: @Bane What? Findall returns a normal python list of strings.

Comment: I just tried it - for me it works perfectly, and `type(links)` gives me a `<type 'list'>`.

Comment: In the original, `a` is a generator. In your rewrite, `a` is a list.

Comment: yes i know, i noted that in my edit, the OP was trying to understand what the code was doing, this was a way to explain it.